# iOS [textfield.text floatValue] returns 0 when text is less than 1

Tags: objective-c, ios, floating-point, uitextfield

I have a currency-converter-type app that I'm working on, and I have a problem. There is a text box, and to get the value of the number that the user enters, I use:

```
float myfloat = [textfield.text floatValue];
```

This works fine, unless the number entered in the text box is between 0 and 1, in which case it returns 0.00000 (or however many decimals there are).

So I was wondering if there is a problem with my code, or if there is a different thing I could try.

Comment: Does the number have locale-specific decimal separator? `floatValue` is not aware of the locale, so it may be the problem. Could you `NSLog` the text, and update the question with an example of text that fails to convert?